# Error: object cannot be converted to TreeNode type (stack error while passing it in function) a question on trees on LeetCode

Tags: java, generics, methods, tree, stack

I'm working on the LeetCode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-preorder-traversal.

When I create the stack in the `solution` method and pass it to the `traverse` method, the compiler gives `error: object cannot be converted to TreeNode (type)`.

However, when I put that line inside the `traverse` method along with the `push(root)` line, then the error is gone.

I don't understand why this difference occurs.

The error occurs on line `TreeNode temp=s.peek();`

My code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        List<Integer> a=new ArrayList<>();
        Stack<TreeNode> s=new Stack<TreeNode>();
        s.push(root);
        traverse(root,s,a);
        return a;
    }

    void traverse(TreeNode root,Stack s,List<Integer> a) {
        if(root==null) return;
         
        TreeNode temp=s.peek();
        
        while(!s.isEmpty())
        {   
            TreeNode temp=s.peek();
            a.add((temp.val));
            s.pop();
            if(temp.right!=null)
                s.push((temp.right));
            if(temp.left!=null)
                s.push((temp.left));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add generics to your Stack parameter. The signature should be

```java
void traverse(TreeNode root, Stack<TreeNode> s, List<Integer> a);
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise, `TreeNode temp = s.peek();` doesn't make sense on a structure implicitly typed `Stack<Object>`. You'd need to cast the `Object` to a `TreeNode` in order to pass compilation, which is unsafe and unnecessary.

Conversely, in case it's not obvious, when you move the declaration and initialization into the method and remove the parameter, `Stack<TreeNode> s = new Stack<TreeNode>();` correctly specifies the generic type so the `peek` assignment to `TreeNode` types will compile.